# Execute javascript on kendo popup editor

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-scheduler

I have popup editors for my grids and scheduler. The editors are defined with a kendo-template (MVVM).  I would like to execute some javascript when these editors are opened, with access to the model currently being edited. I know the trick to execute JS, but not how to get access to the model.

```
<script id="my-editor" type="text/x-kendo-template" title="Edit Event">
    <div class="k-edit-form-container">
        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: taskId" />

        <div class="k-edit-label">
            <label for="title">Title</label>
        </div>
        <div data-container-for="title" class="k-edit-field">
            <input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="title" data-bind="value:title">
        </div>

        <div class="k-edit-label">
            <label for="start">Start Date</label>
        </div>
        <div data-container-for="start" class="k-edit-field">
            <input id="eventStartInput" type="text" data-role="datepicker" name="start" data-bind="value:start">
        </div>

        <div class="k-edit-label">
            <label for="currentHatId">Hat</label>
        </div>
        <div id="hatContainer" data-container-for="currentHatId" class="k-edit-field" disabled>
        </div>

    <script>

        jQuery(function(){


            jQuery('<select data-bind="value: currentHatId" name="currentHatId"/>')
                .appendTo(jQuery('#hatContainer'))
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    dataTextField: 'Name',
                    dataValueField: 'HatId',
                    optionLabel: '-- choose hat --',
                    dataSource: { type: 'odata-v4', transport: { read: { url: 'odata/Hats' } } }
                });

            //I want access to the 'bound' model here!
        })
    <\/script>
</script>
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you provide a working demo of your scenario for us ?

Comment: Basically I would like to react to changes in the model in ways that the MVVM binding can't handle. For example if the start date changes to Fridway, when it was previously on a monday, then display the text 'no work on fridays!'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **edit** event of the scheduler, I have access to the model being edited. So I tried the following:

I configuered the Scheduler to create a new ScheduleEditor instance:

```
edit: (e: kendo.ui.SchedulerEditEvent) => { new ScheduleEditor(e); }
```

Then my ScheduleEditor looks like this:

```
class ScheduleEditor
{
    private _event: kendo.ui.SchedulerEditEvent;

    constructor(e: kendo.ui.SchedulerEditEvent)
    {
        this._event = e;
        e.event.bind('change', (x: any) => { this.eventChanged(x) });
    }

    private eventChanged(x: any)
    {
        console.log('{0} changed', x.field);
    }

    public static initDropDowns(): void
    {
        jQuery('<select data-bind="value: currentHatId" name="currentHatId"/>')
            .appendTo(jQuery('#hatContainer'))
            .kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: 'Name',
                dataValueField: 'HatId',
                valuePrimitive: true,
                optionLabel: '-- choose hat --',
                dataSource: { type: 'odata-v4', transport: { read: { url: 'odata/Hats' } } }
            });
    }
}
```

Note the **valuePrimitive** = true, as this was a problem for me.

Calling *initDropdowns()* from the constructor did not initialize drop downs to correct value, so call it from the template:

```
    </div>
</div>
<script>

    jQuery(function(){
        ScheduledRecipeEditor.initDropDowns();
    })
<\/script>
```

Now in my ScheduleEditor instance I can react to changes in the model. Hope this helps someone. It should be the same for the popup editor on a grid as well.